# How do i fix the errors?

Tags: android, audio

I read Hello Android book.The program will play a sound that i copy in raw folder but the program is not run and gives errors.

errors:

activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field

temp cannot be resolved or is not a field

Audio.java

```
package org.example.audio;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Audio extends Activity{
    private MediaPlayer up;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        up=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.Guilty);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
  MediaPlayer mp;
      switch(keyCode){
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
      mp=up;
      break;
  default:
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
mp.seekTo(0);
mp.start();
return true;
    }
}
```

Please help me that i fix the errors.
Cheers.

Comment: Ok but my problem still is not resolved :(

Comment: what's the problem ? Once check whether the R.java file is being generated or not

Comment: My problem was solved_ the program not have errors and the program is compiled_ but it does not play any sound. Why?? res/layout/activity_main.xml in my post above brought up. Please help me. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

remove the line

```
import android.R;
```

and import the R for appropriate package

in this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

remove the entire line and type till  setContentView(R and give a ctrl+space . You will asked to import few packages among which you need to import a package which contains your project name ( and not android.R)

or else remove the line   import android.R;  and simply clean the project and build it

Answer (score 1):

First delete the line:

```
import android.R;
```

Then if you are using Eclipse try cleaning your project:

**Project** -> **Clean...**

If you have an error in one of your resource files Eclipse automatically imports the `android.R` file when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, which is *frustrating*. Double check the **Package Explorer** window for the error icon on your `res` folder and fix any errors you may find there.

---

The `R` file is an integral aspect of any Java / Android project. It is where the compiler stores references to your resources, like your `activity_main` layout and `temp` sound file.  By importing a foreign `R` file you will receive an error everywhere you try to use your `R` references (`R.layout.activity_main`) because you are trying to look for them in another project.

Answer (score 1):

this is because system can't resolve your R.java file. you use android.R and you call your resource.So remove android.R then clean and build project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer.
I remove import android.R and i copy another song in res/raw.(i edit my first post) but the program has two errors.

Guilty cannot be resolved or is not a field

When i remove android.R with temp music, the program was run but not have sound. i change the sound with another sound and the program was not run :(( why?

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```