# R.java file not present and not coming back.

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I generated a new Android project on Eclipse and the R.file is missing. I tried various procedures to try get it back, like cleaning the project and rebuilding it etc. but none of these solved my problem.

I am using Eclipse Indigo and running it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
I am thinking that I may need to install missing software from the Android SDK Manager but I'm not too sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you have tried *cleaning the project*, *executing the project*, *restarting eclipse*, *changing a value in your `layout.xml` and saving it* and *closing & reopening the project*? I'd give all these a shot first.

Comment: This link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating

Comment: This link might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545170/how-do-i-fix-the-errors/12545190#12545190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't import you R in your Java class even after cleaning the project,  then you have a critical mistake in you XML files e.g.

1) ERROR in any of your`Layout` xml files

2) Any of the XML files name are included spaces, capital letters or start with number.

3) Any of your `drawable` images name contain capital letters, spaces or start with number.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of my suggestions

1.clean your eclipse

```
./eclipse -clean
```

2.close and open your project back

3.make sure you select correct android SDK for your project. check your android manifesto to identify it.